# How to run xampp in Microsoft Virtual PC's Windows XP?

Tags: php, cross-browser, xampp

Firefox and IE 7 are installed. I use MS Virtual PC for testing website in IE6 it works oon live site but I use XAMPP to render PHP files but h.ttp://localhost is not working Virtually running XP with IE6.

Comment: Might want to elaborate a bit on what it means to be "not working"?

Comment: @Darkwoof see In virtually running XP i can open website from internet but when i type to run local website http://localhost in browser nothing happens because XAMPP is not installed on Virtual XP image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a XAMPP server running on your development machine, that you can access natively from http://localhost right?

The copy of Windows XP running inside Virtual PC is a completely separate machine. On this machine, localhost refers to the virtual machine, rather than your development machine.

You need to connect over the network to the development machine. If the IP address of your development machine is 123.123.123.123, you should be able to connect to it using http://123.123.123.123

Comment: yes u guess exactly what i'm asking. oK i will try as u said.

Comment: wow , very much thanks it's working now. Now i can test my Wordpress theme on IE6 using Xampp and Virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the IIS is on. If you're using Apache, make sure IIS is OFF.

Comment: I'm on virtually running XP. no IIS is there

Comment: So, just to clarify, you're running the web site on a server, then on that server you've got a Virtual PC box. It's inside this box that you're not able to run localhost from the browser? If so, find the name of the server and use that instead, i.e. http://servername/.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem - I personally gave up and used Wamp - which worked fine. Know it's not the most helpful answer...

+

just a thought - have you tried 127.0.0.1?

I ask since some XP updates caused the loopback address to stop working for a while. If you've just installed a fresh XP perhaps the updates that fixed that haven't been applied yet.